# Fried rice jumps out of the pan

Tags: frying, rice

On frying cooked, parboiled rice from yesterday, some grains jumps out of the pan every other second, creating a mess. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be due to the fact that it is parboiled and still slightly wet. When stir frying, you're probably adding oil, so I think the popping might be due to the condition of having water with oil.
When making fried rice, I use "day old" rice. This rice has a slightly firmer texture, so that it stands up to stir frying, and it is not damp like fresh or parboiled rice.

Give this a shot and let me know if your fried rice still comes out like you want it to.

Comment: The rice was still day old. I'll try non-parboiled next time and see if it escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not buy a [grease or splatter screen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007VO0DU) to place over the pan?

Comment: I like your suggestion, but when frying rice it's necessary to stir quite a lot so may not completely sort the problem.